# Angular order by key ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the next map:

```
{
    1: [
        "John": 123,
        "Doe": 234 
    ],
    2: [
        "John": 456,
        "Doe": 345   
    ]
    //and so on...
}
```

I have to display them with ng-repeat sorted by index and then with inner ng-repeat sorted by value:

> - 2
>
>   - Doe 234
>   - John 123
> - 1
>
>   - John 456
>   - Doe 345

I tried to find the solution but didn't find anyting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO will help you with code you have written but is not here to write code for you.

Comment: Bad data structure using object instead of array of objects. You can't order an object. Either fix source or map this to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to order by key when you use [angular-underscore](https://github.com/floydwch/angular-underscore)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in pairs(obj) | orderBy:first:true"> Key: {{ item[0] }}; Value: {{item[1]}}</div>
```

In your case it can look like this:

HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="obj in pairs(data) | orderBy:first:true">

  <li>{{ obj[0] }}</li>

  <ul ng-repeat="item in pairs(obj[1]) | orderBy:last:true">
       <li> {{ item[0] }} {{item[1]}}</li>
  </ul>

</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.data = {
  1:{
     'John':123,
     'Doe':234
    },
  2:{
     'John':456,
     'Doe':345
    }};
```

See [working Plunker with your case](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wdrg7GzdjXcRkylaJMrF?p=preview)

To reverse order just change `orderBy:first:true` to `orderBy:first:false`.